# Connecting to Snowflake cloud warehouse to accessing data tables in QGIS

Tags: qgis, cloud-gis, snowflake

Is there a way in QGIS to connect to a Snowflake cloud data warehouse using ODBC, or other? I would like to access this data storage to natively create spatial content by accessing the WKT, Geography, etc. Or by creating an X,Y using the lat/longs stored in the table.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to connect QGIS to Snowflake using an ODBC connection as long as your Snowflake tables follow the OGR naming convention i.e. you would need to have a table called GEOMETRY_COLUMNS that indicates the names of tables that contain geospatial data, and the format of those data.

You can follow this step-by-step guide on how to create a live layer in QGIS from Snowflake data https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQXd3xyshMw